# SDL IMG_Load() on Mac and Linux return different BitsPerPixel for same image

Tags: c++, linux, image, macos, sdl

I'm using SDL's IMG_Load() function to load a PNG file, both on Linux and on Mac OS X. It works, but the weird part is, that on Linux I get a format with 24 BitsPerPixel and on OS X 32 bpp.

```
SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load("path/to/image.png");
std::cerr << (int)image->format->BitsPerPixel << std::endl;
```

The image file is exactly the same on both systems.

```
$ file data/test_scenario.png
data/test_scenario.png: PNG image data, 640 x 400, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

I would presume that 24bpp is correct, judging from the file output.

Any idea why this happens and how I can circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image` is a new surface and isn't guaranteed to have the same bpp of the original `.png`.

If you just need to print the format info from the `.png` I *guess* should be easy to access the header with a custom function or at least using the `libpng`.

If you need to `blit` with the loaded image you have two option:

- support both the bpp formats where is needed in your app
- create a new surface with your desired bpp and convert `image` once loaded